# Laravel NeoEloquent ignores "CONSTRAINT" on ::create command

Tags: php, neo4j, laravel-5, neoeloquent

So I just started to write my API, and came across this bug:

On creating user that has unique CONSTRAINT twice, There is exception returned, but the node is still being created!

The CONSTRAINT is on "User:access_token" property,
and I'm using the following code:

```
try {
    $userAttributes = [
        "email" => $request->email,
        "access_token"  =>  'aaaa',
        "facebook_id"   =>  'bbbb'
    ];
    $user = new User($userAttributes);
    $user->save();
}catch (Exception $e){}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you please run `:schema` in your Neo4j browser to make sure the constraints were created properly? Seems like the issue is beyond the OGM.

Comment: @Mulkave Here is the output from the schema command:
Indexes
  ON :User(email)        ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :User(access_token) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.access_token IS UNIQUE
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.email IS UNIQUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to the [underlying driver](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) using the REST API instead of executing a Cypher query. As a workaround (at the time of this answer) there's a NeoEloquent branch `1.5-dev` that uses a different driver and it will be used to run Cypher against the database. This branch is still under development but currently fully backward-compatible.

To install it add the version `dev-1.5-dev` to your `composer.json` file and run `composer update vinelab/neoeloquent`.